# Fatal error in launcher: Unable to creat process using "c:\bld\scrapy_345323\_h_env\python.exe"

Tags: scrapy, anaconda

I installed anaconda and python on Windows 7 without errors.
I tried to run an example from scrapy.org.

```
scrapy runspider quotes_spider.py -o quotes.json
```

I got an error:

> Fatal error in launcher: Unable to creat process using “c:\bld\scrapy_345323_h_env\python.exe”

How can I resolve this?

Comment: This question seems to miss a question :) Perhaps if you can also provide context and what you did, what failed, at which step, ... Help people to help you :)

Comment: just I have ran this example from scrapy.org - scrapy runspider quotes_spider.py -o quotes.json from scrapy at a glance

Answer (score 1):

Well for anyone that would like to create his first bot from scrapy.org I can confirm the solution is as follows:

first uninstall scrapy from conda

```
conda uninstall -c conda-forge scrapy
```

and use pip instead as follows:

```
pip install --force-reinstall scrapy
```

I had an astroid 2.2.5 problem, but reinstallation succedeed
and I ran the script succesfully

```
scrapy runspider quotes_spider.py -o quotes.json
```

Anyway you may experience other problems running the example provided **quotes_spider.py**, then I suggest trying locating your spider .py to the same folder as your anaconda prompt (in my case,c:\users\bla bla)

running the anaconda powershell did not work anymore, so I will continue working from anaconda prompt

Comment: This solution worked for me to get it to work on Windows 10